# Duvidas em inserção de dados no banco

Tags: php, html

Ola,
Gostaria de saber se tinha como o campo UNIDADE DE ENSINO aonde existe o input e o select na hora de salva no banco de dados salvo os mesmos como se fosse um só teria como ??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script center>
function show(select_item) {
     if (select_item == "regional1") {
      hiddenDiv.style.visibility='visible';
   hiddenDiv.style.display='block';
   Form.fileURL.focus();
  } 
  else{
   hiddenDiv.style.visibility='hidden';
   hiddenDiv.style.display='RPA';
  }
 }
function populate(verficarpa,resultado){
 var verficarpa = document.getElementById(verficarpa);
 var resultado = document.getElementById(resultado);
    
 resultado.innerHTML = "";
 if(verficarpa.value == "1"){ //Se o valor da regional for 1
  var optionArray = ["|","1|1","2|2"]; //Trazer as informações da RPA 1 e 2, da respectiva regional 1
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "2"){ //Se o valor da regional for 2
  var optionArray = ["|","3|3"]; //Trazer as informações da RPA 3, da respectiva regional 2
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "3"){ //Se o valor da regional for 3
  var optionArray = ["|","4|4","5|5"]; //Trazer as informações da RPA 4 e 5, da respectiva regional 3
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "4"){ //Se o valor da regional for 4
  var optionArray = ["|","6|6"]; //Trazer as informações da RPA 6, da respectiva regional 4
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  resultado.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
function populate2(verficarpa,resultado){ //função para verificar o valor da RPA inserido pelo usuário e habilitar os tipos de unidades de acordo com valor anterior.
 var verficarpa = document.getElementById(verficarpa);
 var resultado = document.getElementById(resultado);
    
 resultado.innerHTML = "";
 if(verficarpa.value == "1"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 1
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"]; //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "2"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 2
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"]; //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "3"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 3
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"]; //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "4"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 4
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"]; //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "5"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 5
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"]; //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 } else if(verficarpa.value == "6"){ //Se o valor da RPA for 6
  var optionArray = ["|","ANEXO|ANEXO","CRECHE|CRECHE","CRECHE ESCOLA|CRECHE ESCOLA","ESCOLA REGULAR|ESCOLA REGULAR","ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL|ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL"];  //retorna os tipos de unidade da respectiva RPA
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  resultado.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
function populate3(verificatipounidade,verificaregional,verificarpa,s4){ //função verificar os valores do tipo da Unidade, Regional e RPA para retornar os valores da Escola
 var verificatipounidade = document.getElementById(verificatipounidade);
 var verificaregional = document.getElementById(verificaregional);
 var verificarpa = document.getElementById(verificarpa);
 var s4 = document.getElementById(s4);
 s4.innerHTML = "";
 //RPA 01
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "1"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "1"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "1"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "1"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "1"){ 
        var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."];  }
 //RPA 02
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "2"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "2"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 }
  if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "2"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "2"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "1" && verificarpa.value == "2"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 //RPA 03
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "2" && verificarpa.value == "3"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "2" && verificarpa.value == "3"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "2" && verificarpa.value == "3"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "2" && verificarpa.value == "3"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "2" && verificarpa.value == "3"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 //RPA 04
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "4"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "4"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "4"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "4"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "4"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 //RPA 05
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "5"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "5"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "5"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "5"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "3" && verificarpa.value == "5"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 } 
 //RPA 06
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ANEXO" && verificaregional.value == "4" && verificarpa.value == "6"){ 
  var optionArray = ["ANEXO  - |ANEXO  - "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE" && verificaregional.value == "4" && verificarpa.value == "6"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CR. M. |CR. M. "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "CRECHE ESCOLA" && verificaregional.value == "4" && verificarpa.value == "6"){ 
  var optionArray = ["CRECHE ESCOLA - |CRECHE ESCOLA - "]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA REGULAR" && verificaregional.value == "4" && verificarpa.value == "6"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 }
 if(verificatipounidade.value == "ESCOLA TEMPO INTEGRAL" && verificaregional.value == "4" && verificarpa.value == "6"){ 
  var optionArray = ["E.M.|E.M."]; 
 }
  for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  s4.options.add(newOption);
 }
}



</script>
<script>
                         function sem_acento(e,args){            
                             if (document.all){var evt=event.keyCode;} // caso seja IE
                             else{var evt = e.charCode;}  // do contrário deve ser Mozilla
                             var valid_chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZWYKÇÁÉÍÓÃÕ.';      // criando a lista de teclas permitidas
                             var chr= String.fromCharCode(evt);      // pegando a tecla digitada
                             if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 ){return true;} // se a tecla estiver na lista de permissão permite-a
                             // para permitir teclas como <BACKSPACE> adicionamos uma permissão para 
                             // códigos de tecla menores que 09 por exemplo (geralmente uso menores que 20)
                             if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 || evt < 9){return true;} 
                       if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>30 || evt <35){return true;} //permite a tecla espaço
                             return false;   // do contrário nega
                         }
                         function so_numero(e,args){            
                             if (document.all){var evt=event.keyCode;} // caso seja IE
                             else{var evt = e.charCode;}  // do contrário deve ser Mozilla
                             var valid_chars = '0123456789';      // criando a lista de teclas permitidas
                             var chr= String.fromCharCode(evt);      // pegando a tecla digitada
                             if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 ){return true;} // se a tecla estiver na lista de permissão permite-a
                             // para permitir teclas como <BACKSPACE> adicionamos uma permissão para 
                             // códigos de tecla menores que 09 por exemplo (geralmente uso menores que 20)
                             if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>-1 || evt < 9){return true;} 
                       if (valid_chars.indexOf(chr)>30 || evt <35){return true;} //permite a tecla espaço
                             return false;   // do contrário nega
                         }       
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<h3>Informe os dados da turma:</h3>
<br/>
Os campos com <span style="color: red">*</span> são de preenchimento obrigatório!
<br/><br/>
<form name="cadastroTurma" method="post" action="/sigep/Unidade de Ensino/pag1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css/Pag.css" />
Regional:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
<select id="regional" name="regional" onchange="populate(this.id,'rpa')" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
RPA:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
<select id="rpa" name="rpa" onchange="populate2(this.id,'tipoUnidade')" required></select>
<br/><br/>
Tipo de Unidade:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
<select id="tipoUnidade" name="tipoUnidade" onchange="populate3(this.id,'regional','rpa','uni')" required></select>
<br/><br/>

Unidade de Ensino:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
<select id="uni" name="uni" required>
<input id='unidade' class='textbox' name='unidade' type='text' maxlength='55' size='55'   onKeyPress='return sem_acento(event);' required />
</select>
<br/><br/>
INEP:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
<input id='unidade' class='textbox' name='unidade' type='text' maxlength='10' size='11'   onKeyPress='return so_numero(event);' required /><br/>

<br/><br/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/finalizar.css">
<input type="submit" class="btfinalizar btn-blue" value="Finalizar" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/voltar.css">
<a href="Unidade de Ensino" class="bt btn-blue">Voltar</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Conexão com o banco de dados.

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <br /><br />
  <!-- Ligação com o banco -->
  <?php include 'css/config.php'; ?>
  <?php
//Variáveis que recebem os dados preenchidos no formulário (cadastroTurmaTela1.html)
$regional=$_POST['regional'];
$rpa=$_POST['rpa'];
$tipoUnidade=$_POST['tipoUnidade'];
$unidade=$_POST['unidade'];
$Inep=$_POST['Inep'];

//Select no banco para selecionar todos os dados solicitados no formulário (alterarTurmaTela1.html)
   $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM cadastros_unidades WHERE unidade LIKE '%".$unidade."%' AND tipoUnidade LIKE '%".$tipoUnidade."%' AND regional LIKE '%".$regional."%' 
   AND rpa LIKE '%".$rpa."%' AND Inep LIKE '%".$Inep."%'");
//Testa se os dados existem no banco, caso exista ele exibe na tela   
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
   if ($row > 0) {
 echo "<html>

<head>

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/sigep/css/css/PagTurma.css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container2'>
Não foi possível efetuar o cadastro da turma, pois a mesma já existe no sistema.
</div>
</body>

</html>";
 
   } else {
//Insert no banco para inserir todos os dados Informados no formulário (cadastroTurmaTela1.html)
$ibd = mysqli_query ($conexao, "INSERT INTO cadastros_unidades (regional,rpa,tipoUnidade,unidade,Inep) 
VALUES ('$regional','$rpa','$tipoUnidade','$unidade','$Inep')");
   echo "<html>

<head>

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/sigep/css/css/PagTurma.css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container2'>
Cadastro realizado com sucesso!
</div>
</body>

</html>";

   }
?>

    <!-- Links da página -->
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <a href="/sigep/cadastros-de-unidade-de-ensino " class="btn btn-blue">Novo cadastro</a>
    <br/>
    <a href=" /Sigep/Unidade de Ensino " class="btn btn-blue">Voltar</a>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sigep/css/css/CDTpag2.css">



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Teria como você deixar como você recebe as variáveis no `/sigep/Unidade de Ensino/pag1` e como você as armazena no banco de dados?

Comment: Da uma olhadinha inserir no final  a /sigep/Unidade de Ensino/pag1.

Answer (score 1):

Tem sim!
No trecho em php, concatene os dois(ou mais) valores que deseja salvar como um só.

Ex. prático de como concatenar valores como se fosse uma variável só:

```
$variavelSo = $_POST['val1'].' | '.$_POST['val2'];
```

Comment: Tem como mostrar um exemplo prático? Isso com certeza irá aumentar muito a qualidade da sua resposta.

Comment: Sua dica ajudou muito cara.. flw